# excel change a string date into a date

Tags: excel, vba

I need to change a string from : Mon, Dec 07, 2015

Into . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 12/07/15

is there an **if** statement like

```
=IF(IFERROR(SEARCH("Dec", B6), 0), "Dec", "")
```

or would it be too complex to try to figure out how make everything line up properly

Any suggestion would work I'm not the best at VBA but I can work with it

Comment: `=text(MID(B6,6,999),"mm/dd/yy)`  get rid of the  `Mon, ` and excel will see it as a date.

Comment: @whitehat Why did you delete your answer?

Comment: This Helps me if it's a date convert it if not copy the one above - . . . . . . . . . . .  =IF((TEXT(MID(B1,6,99),"mm/dd/yy"))="01/00/00",A1,(TEXT(MID(B1,6,999),"mm/dd/yy")))

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to deal with formulas, not VBA. Use this:

```
=DATEVALUE(MID("Mon, Dec 07, 2015";6;100))
```

Not sure if your Excel version separates arguments with ';' or ','. Mine uses ';'.

The last argument, 100, just ensures it reads enough chars of the string.

Remember to format the cell with the formula to show the custom format "mm/dd/yyyy", or it will show a number instead of a date.

Comment: You need to deal with the whole string.  OP said he had a cell with text string of `Mon, Dec 07, 2015` and needs to convert it to a date.  Your formula does not show how to do that.

Comment: Now you need to format it correctly, He wants it in "mm/dd/yy".  Yours will return a 5 digit number.  When you are done you will end up with the same formula as me.

Comment: hmmm, I didn't get that. The final result must be a string? In this case, you have the answer. Just close the opening double-quote.